# how unmarshall xml from two xsd

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have XML file Created from 2 XSD file.

First XSD is here

http://www.mvcr.cz/soubor/priloha-2-schema-xml-pro-zaznamenani-popisnych-metadat-uvnitr-datoveho-balicku-sip-pdf.aspx

Second XSD is here (i need unmarshall DIL etc)

http://www.mvcr.cz/nsesss/v1/nsesss.xsd

And XML file

```
 </mets:agent>
    <mets:agent ID="agent_002" ROLE="CREATOR" TYPE="INDIVIDUAL">

    </mets:agent>
    <mets:agent ID="agent_003" ROLE="ARCHIVIST" TYPE="ORGANIZATION">
        <mets:name>Národní archiv</mets:name>
        <mets:note>70979821</mets:note>
    </mets:agent>
    <mets:agent ID="agent_004" ROLE="ARCHIVIST" TYPE="INDIVIDUAL">
        <mets:name>Karel Dobrý</mets:name>
        <mets:note>odborný archivář</mets:note>
        <mets:note>Oddělení předarchivní péče u organizací státní správy</mets:note>
    </mets:agent>
</mets:metsHdr>
<mets:dmdSec ID="dmd_001">
    <mets:mdWrap MIMETYPE="text/xml" MDTYPE="OTHER" OTHERMDTYPE="NSESSS" MDTYPEVERSION="1.0" LABEL="Schéma XML pro předávání dokumentů a jejich metadat do archivu" xmlns:nsesss="http://www.mvcr.cz/nsesss/v1">


        <mets:xmlData>
            <nsesss:Dil ID="nsesss_001">
                <nsesss:EvidencniUdaje>
                    <nsesss:Identifikace>
                        <nsesss:Identifikator zdroj="ERMS">MV546336Z001</nsesss:Identifikator>
                    </nsesss:Identifikace>
                    <nsesss:Popis>
                        <nsesss:Nazev>1</nsesss:Nazev>
                        <nsesss:Komentar>První díl v rámci součásti</nsesss:Komentar>
                    </nsesss:Popis>
                    <nsesss:Poznamky>
```

I have generated by JAXB java Class from XSD and i ged first part of XML (Agent etc), but how i get DIL etc?

Answer (score 0):

Create xsd that actually describes your xml.
You can import the individual parts inside your complete schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="xxx.xsd" namespace="http://www.mvcr.cz/nsesss/v1"/>
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="..." namespace="..."/> 
  ...
</xsd:schema>
```

to refer to the